# Error initializing CoreML converted model

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, coreml

Error instantiating converted caffe model.

> [core] MLModelAsset: load failed with error Error
> Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Error in declaring network."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error in declaring network.}
>
> 2017-07-15 18:30:24.902963-0700 How Holo[7288:1478467] [core]
> MLModelAsset: modelWithError: load failed with error Error
> Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Error in declaring network."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error in declaring network.} fatal
> error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
> Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Error in declaring network."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error in declaring network.}:

Here is how the CNN looks like: http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/gist/d465d6908aa6b278b1f6d308d26ea2f7

Help is appreciated

Comment: It should be related to how you load your model in your project, not the model itself.